# Ejecutar código cuando el ScrollTop sea igual a la posición de un elemento una única vez

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Intento hacer que un codigo se ejecute **una sola vez** cuando el `scrollTop` de la pagina sea igual a la posicion de un elemento, osea cuando el elemento sea visible.

Ya lo logre, el problema esta ahora en que cada vez que el `scrollTop` es igual a la posición del elemento, **se ejecuta cuantas veces el usuario pasa por allí**, no quiero eso, solo quiero que se ejecute **una sola vez** cuando se cargue la pagina.

Aqui el codigo:

```js
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 780) {
    let rangos = document.getElementsByClassName('rangos');
    for (let rango of rangos) {
      let elRango = rango;
      let idRango = rango.getAttribute('id');
      conteo(elRango, idRango);
    }

    function conteo(el, num) {
      var cont = 0;
      var id = setInterval(function() {
        el.innerHTML = cont + ' %';
        cont++;
        if (cont > num) {
          clearInterval(id);
        }
      }, 70);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="90" class="rangos"> % </span>
<span id="87" class="rangos"> % </span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes crear una variable lógica y evaluarla en el condicional junto al scrollTop, y una vez lanzada la función la anulas. Algo así:

```js
var trigger = true;

$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  if (($(window).scrollTop() >= 780) && (trigger)){
    trigger = false;
    let rangos = document.getElementsByClassName('rangos');
    for (let rango of rangos) {
      let elRango = rango;
      let idRango = rango.getAttribute('id');
      conteo(elRango, idRango);
    }

    function conteo(el, num) {
      var cont = 0;
      var id = setInterval(function() {
        el.innerHTML = cont + ' %';
        cont++;
        if (cont > num) {
          clearInterval(id);
        }
      }, 70);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="90" class="rangos"> % </span>
<span id="87" class="rangos"> % </span>
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta, funciono, era tan facil? jajaja, Gracias.